# Add Tooltip via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, image, tooltip

I am trying to add a tooltip that shows an image.  This needs to be done via JS injection.  I can use jQuery.  For testing - I am using the same image for both the view, and when a user hovers over the image it should show the same image in the tooltip.  Here is my current code that is not working:

```
<img src="https://images.quickbase.com/si/16/751-binary_view.png"  onload="$(this).tooltip({content: "<img src='https://images.quickbase.com/si/16/751-binary_view.png'/>"});">
```

Comment: Which tooltip library have you used?

Comment: Just use [Qtip2](http://qtip2.com/demos) or any other tooltip plugin.

Comment: jQuery tooltip: https://jqueryui.com/tooltip/

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT:** I've added a `data-tooltip` to tag the images with tooltips (in contrast to those that don't).

You must escape the quotes (at least):

```
<img src="https://images.quickbase.com/si/16/751-binary_view.png"
  onload="$(this).tooltip({
    content: \"<img src='https://images.quickbase.com/si/16/751-binary_view.png'/>\"
  });"
/>
```

Maybe it's better to keep it outside the tag altogether.

```
<img src="https://images.quickbase.com/si/16/751-binary_view.png"
  data-tooltip="true" />
```

and somewhere in the header:

```
$(function () {
  $("img[data-tooltip='true']").each(function () {
    $(this).on("load", function () {
     var content;

     content = "<img src='{src}'/>".replace("{src}", $(this).attr("src"));
     $(this).tooltip({ "content": content });
    });
  });
});
```

The `data-tooltip="true"` attribute allows you to choose exactly which images should have a tooltip and which not (simply omit it in the latter case).